# `x in pandas.core.series.Series` returns True even though there is no such value in it

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas series object that contains bunch of IDs. I wanted to filter out rows of other dataframe by checking if their ID was present in my pandas series object:

`DATA['y'] = DATA['ID'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in IDs else 0)`

I noticed that ID 279779 in DATA had '1' in column 'y', even though that ID was not present in my IDs series object. I ran following line:
`279779 in IDs` , which returned `True`, but following code did not print anything:

```
for id in IDs:
    if id == 279779:
        print('found')
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Why does `279779 in IDs` return `True` when there is no such ID in IDs?

Comment: `279779 in IDs` checks whether 279779 is in the index of the series. The best way to check if its in the values is `(IDs == 279779).any()` or `279779 in IDs.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

`1` is equal to `True` in Python.

You may want to try with casting string type to ID column to avoid 1 be taken as bool value:

```
DATA['y'] = DATA['ID'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: 1 if x in IDs.values else 0)
```

Comment: That does not really answer my question, I am not looking for solution. I simply did `list(IDs)` and it works fine. I just want to know why `279779 in IDs` returns True.

Comment: If you check for values it returns True in both cases as in this short example:

`IDs = [i*100 for i in range(10)] + [279779] `
`df = pd.DataFrame(IDs, columns = ['IDs'] )`
`279779 in IDs, 279779 in df.IDs.values`

Comment: And if you are checking series index then you can use `IDs.index` instead

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have to make sure, what is the type of IDs?

if it is a number then you cannot iterate over a number in  for loop.

according to your for loop, if IDs is String then your for loops `"id"` label will have a single character on every iteration like:

`"2","7","9","7","7","9"`  indexes will be `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

and because of this on very first and each iteration the if condition will work as follows:

first iteration

```
 id= "2"

 if id == 279779:
    print("Found")
```

this will happen till last iteration and if condition will always be False .

And my guess is, IDs object has a list with String. Please do check that.